# Windows Alternative to Rsync?

Tags: sync, file-transfer, remote

I'm trying to setup a file sync between the file server at my house and the one at my brother's so that we each have offsite backups of important data.  Both systems are running Windows (XP on one, 7 on the other).
I like the fact that rsync will only transfer *part* of a file, the part that has changed, and not the whole thing...saving a lot of bandwidth.  But I have had very little luck getting it to work properly.  I tried using DeltaCopy, but it's interface is horrible, and while it will work within my LAN it always fails to connect when remote. (See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/65985/issues-with-deltacopy-when-syncing-over-the-internet) for more details on that)

Is there another alternative program that runs on windows and has similar functionality?  So far the only other option I can see is using FTP and something like SyncBackPro...but that is just going to transfer the whole file...and only having 512kbps upload bandwidth makes that a total pain.

**Edit:**  To clarify some more, the backup I'm doing needs to scan several hundreds of thousands of files, adding up to more than 400GB, on each end...  which is why I'm not using an intermediary service like LIVE for the transfer...

**Edit 2:**  Also, these backups need to be preformed over a *remote connection* and without a VPN...  Meaning that using Windows File Shares (SMB) is out of the question...

Comment: 512 kb/s? Wow... And you're in the US?

Comment: I live in Romania and have 30 Mb/s download and 4 Mb/s upload for about 10$. Having 512 kb/s should be unacceptable.

Comment: haha...5Mb/s down and 512kb/s up and I pay $60 for it...welcome to the land of the free :D

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/rsync/?platform=windows

Answer (score 23):

There is [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) which will let you run rsync in windows.  We use it on one of our servers to back up about 140k files.  FTP just couldn't handle that.

Answer (score 14):

rsync does work on windows - [deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)  is a wrapper around it - though you can use the rsync packaged in it on its own.

Comment: I like this a bit better than cwrsync as it seems slightly more "Windows-ified" - ultimately they do exactly the same thing.

Comment: If using this rsync, be aware that it expects cygwin paths.. e.g. /cygdrive/c/users/

Answer (score 8):

[rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) uses the rsync algorithms for transmitting only file differences and it keeps file history.  The history part is could be a very important feature for your backup scheme.

I have been using in around the (microsoft only) office for over a year.  It just works.

Comment: Interesting find.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest you give [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) a shot. It's part of Vista/7/2008 by default and in the newer version has mirror support. It also supports resume and networking shares.

Comment: Any way to get this to work over something other than a windows file share?

Comment: If you have large files that often have small changes robocopy is very network inefficient.  It transmits the entire file even if only the last few bytes have changed.

Comment: If rschuler is right, then Robocopy is nothing like rsync, and this is a bad answer.

Comment: Robocopy was less than half the speed in a 4 GB download on the same line compared to other options. It couldn't resume broken transfers. My first impression is that it's overrated. Since then I found better tools but don't have enough experience to comment on those here. I did use Deltacopy and it was pretty cool. See another answer on it in this thread.

Comment: Since it's a default package in Windows, it's useful in corporate environment where you do not have the permission to install any third party software on the systems(At least without going through a long chain of processes before you're allowed to install it).

Comment: default package in Windows is enough for me !

Answer (score 5):

I like [Unison File Synchronizer](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)...if you don't mind using commandline tools. It is fast, it scans files for changes much quicker than rsync. Similar to rsync, it only transfers changed portions of files.

Answer (score 5):

Beginning with Windows Vista, the Offline files feature (also known as Client-Side Caching) will automatically sync over slow connections and only transfer the changed portions of files (much like rsync).

I mention this as a possible solution, although you specifically mention that SMB is not an option for you.  If you were to give the systems routable addresses (such as IPv6 addresses), you could probably connect over the Internet without a VPN. I do this regularly, and it works well when the ISP isn't blocking the SMB ports. I wouldn't necessarily recommend this for you because one client is running XP, and your ISPs may be blocking SMB. Still, I wanted to mention that the capability is built into Windows Vista/7 when the connectivity is available.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Windows Live Mesh.  There's an option in Mesh that enables you to sync between machines, bypassing Live Desktop and its quota.  So you can sync as much info as you want.  It's simple to do this:  on a folder that's Mesh enabled, choose Sync Settings > Live Desktop > select "Never with this device.".

That setting will skip syncing data with Live and sync directly between devices in your Mesh.

Comment: Mesh rocks.  Seriously.

Comment: With this method are there still limitations like file size, number of files in a directory, etc?  This would be a dealbreaker for me...

Comment: Adam:  Here are some limit numbers from over a year ago.  Not sure if there are changes since this was published: http://blogs.msdn.com/livemesh/archive/2008/08/13/the-potential-of-live-mesh-is-limitless.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You could install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com) on both machines, install an ssh server on the remote machine (such as cygwin's, or perhaps http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/), and then use rsync on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

[BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) is an open source backup solution that uses rsync amongst other things.  I think this may do what you want.

Alternatively, there is always [Windows Live Sync](https://sync.live.com).  It is a very simple and robust way to sync Windows and Macs, but with the following limits:

> A maximum of 20 folders (or
>   "libraries") may by synced, including
>   libraries shared over the internet.
>   Each library can contain a maximum of
>   20,000 files and each file cannot
>   exceed 4GB.

If what you want to sync fits in those parameters, give it a go.