# Windows alternative for rsync

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, rsync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Alternative to Rsync?](https://superuser.com/questions/69514/windows-alternative-to-rsync)

I have an external hard drive connected to my Windows7 and I want it to automatically sync with a folder in my hard drive.

On the Linux side I'm aware of *rsync* which is the perfect solution for me now. Unfortunately I have to use Windows 7 these days and I am looking for a Windows alternative that is easy to use.

Suggestions?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows

Comment: Brahims: a lot of your questions have been closed as duplicates or migrated to other sites. When asking a question, please double check first that the question has not been asked before. Take a look at the [advanced search features](http://superuser.com/search), and look at the "related questions" box that appears when asking. Also make sure your question is on-topic as defined by the [FAQ#questions] before asking it. Having too many closed questions can result in your account being automatically blocked by the system from asking new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have not used it in a while, but [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155) would be my first suggestion.

Comment: oooh...look, yup definitely a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

Try "robocopy", Windows 7's in-built utility.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

(Though, I think the question may be a duplicate.)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/69514/windows-alternative-to-rsync

Comment: That's it, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I use [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com), backing up to a local drive is free. The only time you actually pay is if you use CrashPlan Central (their online backup service).

Previously I used [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/).

Answer (score 1):

I use [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) (rsync for Windows)