# Software, with a RAID / cloud-backup like capability

Tags: windows-7, linux, backup

I would like to have a backup, on my own PCs, laptop, server. Wherever I can install that software, and set this up.

Let's say I want to have a 50gb of storage. So I install this software on every PC/laptop (maybe server too), and select the places where I want to keep the files. If I have two HDDs in my PC, I would like to have this directory on both. (This is where the software RAID like capability comes in.)

Is there anything like this?
Or just similar to this?

Comment: (All I could think of is having an SVN repo, but that's not really decentralized.)

Comment: A distributed file system (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_file_system) could do what you're asking, I'm not sure about OS support/features, though. The wikipedia article above have some links that you might find interesting.

Comment: Seems like setting AFS up for example would be quite hard. But I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: Related question http://superuser.com/questions/128590/alternative-to-dropbox-on-my-server

Answer (score 1):

You can use programs like [rsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync), [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx) or (I think) [LiveMesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh-devices-sync-upgrade-ui) to make periodically synchronised duplicates of folders across multiple disks and/or across multiple computers. Locally and remotely. You can automate this with Windows scheduler. LiveMesh isn't really like the other two but may do what you want.

See

- [Windows Alternative to Rsync?](https://superuser.com/q/69514/52492)
- [Sync two external harddrives?](https://superuser.com/q/141268/52492)
- [What application can I use to synchronize several machines devices?](https://superuser.com/q/201007/52492)

Answer (score 1):

As alternatives to the other mentioned local file sync tools such as rsync, robocopy, etc. I would recommend DropBox if you need the files to be accessible and bidirectionally synced and then for backup/versioning/archiving I would recommend CrashPlan on top of it which will allow you to backup to your local drives as well as to other computers or even your friends which are also running CrashPlan.

[CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/crashplan.html)

[DropBox](http://www.dropbox.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Go for Crashplan - the local backup capability is excellent and the cloud option is cheap - as long as you've got enough upstream bandwidth to use it.

Comment: Yeah but their plans cost way too much. One PC is ok. But if I want two? Or three? (I've got a server, a laptop, and a desktop.) So I would have to buy the family one. Which costs A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Unison File Synchronizer for this type of situation.

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/

A little complicated to set it up (you need SSH keys on all the computers), but it works beautifully. The software is no longer updated by the developer, but to me it had every feature I needed so I didn't care about future updates.